# Make box with scroll start scrolled to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, chat

I'm building a user interface for a chat web-app. So there's a div in which messages appear in a list, and the user can scroll through it. But as it's a messaging app, I want the div to be scrolled to the bottom if the user doesn't do anything (from the load of the page until the user scrolls) - and it would be great if the div could keep scrolled to the bottom when the user scrolled to the bottom again.

How could I code this? (better with css and html only rather than using javascript)

(Sorry about my bad syntax, I'm not from an English-speaking country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a chat box with a `form` at bottom, you can set `focus` on one of the `form` element *or the last text generated in your chat box*.:
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/CztIx/

```
onload= function() {
  frmfcs =document.getElementById('form1');
  frmfcs.focus();
}
```

---

*The attribute autofocus would have been an option if it was cross browser : here one of my old test : http://dabblet.com/gist/5271266*

Comment: the use : name the function and call it from your update content function

Comment: I want to keep the form at the bottom of the viewport all time (I'm using `position:fixed` to accomplish that) but could I use that same approach to set `focus` on the last message of the list and get the same result?

Comment: What are using `tabindex` for in the example? Is it neccesary? I'm trying to focus the last element of the list and there are no errors, but nothing happens

Comment: `tabindex` attribute allows `li` to take `focus`, else , only links and `form` elements takes it.

Comment: And is there a better way for making `li` elements focusable than adding that attribute to every list element? Any css rule?

Comment: nop, you can use a javascript loop to set this attribute or only to the last one each time list is reload via ajax and if new content.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById('name');
element.scrollTop = element.offsetHeight
```

Unfortunately, not possible with pure CSS so far.